# using graphql and simple express nodejs setup caussing bugs and errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I am building a simple graphql express setup by following this tutorial::
https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-build-a-note-taking-app-with-graphql-and-react-part-1-of-2-febf1aeda091

But some errors are coming:

my files are::

## schema.js

```
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');
const { resolvers } = require('./resolvers');

const typeDefs = `
 type Note {
  _id: ID!
  title: String!,
  date: Date,
  content: String!
 }
scalar Date
type Query {
  allNotes: [Note]
 }`;

exports.schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
});
```

## resolvers.js

```
const Note = require("./models/note");

exports.resolvers = {
    Query : {
       async allNotes(){
           return await Note.find();
       }
    }
};
```

## models/note.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const NoteSchema = new Schema({
    title : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
exports.Note = mongoose.model('Note', NoteSchema);
```

## app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {graphlHTTP} = require("express-graphql");
const {schema} = require("./schema");

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://hadoop:hadoop123@ecomdb-hcm1m.mongodb.net/nodeapi2?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true    
}).then(() => console.log('DB Connected'))

mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`)
});

const app = express();
const PORT = 4300;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "Notetaking API v1"
  });
});

app.use(
    "/graphql",
    graphlHTTP({
      schema: schema,
      graphiql: true
    })
);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

==========================================================

Everything is looks fine but still "TypeError: graphlHTTP is not a function" error is coming.
I am attaching the screenshots. Please suggests how to fix that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo in app.js. You need to import graphqlHTTP instead of graphlHTTP and use the same.

const {graphqlHTTP} = require("express-graphql");

Here is the npm pacakge link.
https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql